# Ubuntu 20.04 snap installed Chromium - Impossible to read Nextcloud folders

Tags: chromium, snap, nextcloud

Since Ubuntu 20.04 has switched to snap package, I can't upload/download anymore files inside ~/Nextcloud/

Obviously, everything works normally using the OS file browser, command line and Firefox.

[image]

Comment: What are the permissions for that folder? Is there a mount point along the path?

Answer (score 0):

`snap` applications can only read the user's home directory and, depending on the configuration, the user's /media/ mountpoints.

That is the current security model.

All other mount points are off-limits.

Comment: Very likely is not your choice, anyway regarding security, the number one rule to consider IMHO is: "The best home security alarm becomes the worst system ever if leave you out of your home". In this case, Nextcloud folder is not a mount point but a normal home subfolder like Documents, Downloads etc...